# `{} {}some` vs`{} {,some}` in the `-exec` option of the `find` command

Tags: bash, find

I want to add some files in the directory with some suffix. I usually do this:

`find . -name '*01' -exec mv {} {}bar \;`

But recently I came across another version of this command that does the same thing:

`find . -name '*01' -exec mv {}{,bar} \;`

Why does this work? What is this syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is [`brace expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html). But...

Better use:

```
find . -name '*01' -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$1.bar"' bash {} \;
```

or even better, using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

```
shopt -s globstar # enable recursion with **

rename 's/$/.bar/' **/*01
```

Comment: Added Perl's rename command, shorter, cleaner, better ;)

Comment: Thanks, didn't remember that `{,bar}` is "" and "bar". But why is the option you suggested better?  I also don't use {} inside double quotes and such.

Comment: Have you read https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/12574 ?

Comment: Yes. From what I understand, it's dangerous when I call `find ... -exec sh -c "some cmd {}"` But I don't run the intermediate shell `sh`, in which I pass the substitution in the argument.